# What are the package names for Facebook Lite and Messenger Lite?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I was able to open Facebook and Messenger apps though my app using `com.facebook.katana` and `com.facebook.orca`. However, there are also **lite** versions of the two. The thing is, I couldn't find the package name of these apps. I tried writing `com.facebook.katana.lite`, `...lite.katana` .. and so on. But no success...
How can I find out the package names? Or is there someone who knows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Facebook App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana): `com.facebook.katana`
[Facebook Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.lite): `com.facebook.lite`
[Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca): `com.facebook.orca`
[Messenger Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.mlite): `com.facebook.mlite`

If you want to search for package name of any app, just search it in the play store from web browser and get the id parameter from the URL.

Comment: what about messenger lite ?

Comment: whoa, checking it out bro :)

Comment: ha, got it, I didn't know that, thanks for the quick response. Btw, do you know how to open Messenger Lite with particular person ?

Comment: I used the same method which works for Messenger but it doesn't work for Lite. I changed the packageName to mlite... its better to show in code, right ?

Comment: Happy to help. :)